# Python regex: Search across multilines

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a python script to parse file with following data:

```
// some more entries with different structures.
leaf a include-1 {
 type 1;
 description "test1";
}
leaf b include-2 {
 type string;
 description "test2";
}
// some other entries
```

I want to get all my leaf names and its description
ex:

```
a test1
b test2
```

I tried doing the following:

```
 regExStr = '^leaf.*{.*include-.*}$'
 compiled =  re.compile(regExStr, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
 matched = compiled.search(line)
```

So in other words I want to begin my search with `leaf` followed by any number character followed by `{`followed by `include-`followed by anything 
and then ends with `}`

Since I have used re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE my `.` also includes new line.

But I am not able to get the desired results. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try removing the start of string and end of string characters.  Then test in one of the online python regex testers.

Answer (score 1):

Searching across multiple lines with a regex is possible with [`re.S` (=`re.DOTALL`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) modifier. To be able to match a beginning of line, [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) (multiline mode) should be used. The names are a bit tricky, but they can be combined.

You can obtain your results with an updated regex:

```
p = re.compile(r'^leaf\s+(\S+)[^{]*\{[^}]*\bdescription\s+"([^"]+)"[^}]*}', re.S|re.M)
test_str = "leaf a include-1 {\n type 1;\n description \"test1\";\n}\nleaf b include-2 {\n type string;\n description \"test2\";\n}"
print ["%s %s"%(x.group(1), x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DnHx4h)

Output:

```
['a test1', 'b test2']
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - beginning of line
- `leaf` - `leaf` literally
- `\s+(\S+)` - 1 or more whitespace and then captures a sequence of 1 or more non-whitespace characters
- `[^{]*` - 0 or more characters other than `{`
- `\{` - a literal  `{`
- `[^}]*` - 0 or more characters other than `}`
- `\bdescription` - whole word `description`
- `\s+"([^"]+)"` - 1 or more whitespace symbols, then a `"`, then captures 1 or more characters other than a double quote, and then matches another double quote
- `[^}]*` - 0 or more characters other than `}`
- `}` - a literal `}`.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same you can use a dict and str.split:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("leaf"):
            key = line.split(None,2)[1]
            next(f)
            val = next(f).split()[-1].strip(";\n")
            d[key]=val

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
('a', '"test1"')
('b', '"test2"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) so that you can iterate over multiple matches:

```
import re

line = """leaf a include-1 {
 type 1;
 description "test1";
}
leaf b include-2 {
 type string;
 description "test2";
}"""

regExStr = '^leaf (\w) include-.*?description \"(.*?)\";.*?}'
compiled =  re.compile(regExStr, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
matched = compiled.finditer(line)
for m in matched:
    print m.groups()
```

---

Prints:

```
('a', 'test1')
('b', 'test2')
```

---

You can see that each result is a tuple with the first element (`m.group(1)`) being your leaf name and the second element (`m.group(2)`) being the description.